# Symfony 4.2 Problem with FOS Comment Bundle, could not load routing.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, foscommentbundle

I am struggling with installation of FOS Comment Bundle. I have Symfony v 4.2.1.
I followed instructions from documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md

I ommitted only this part:
`assetic:
    bundles: [ "FOSCommentBundle" ]`
Because assetic is not working with Symfony ^4. I installed assets by: `bin/console assets:install`

I get that error:

> LoadException: Cannot load resource "@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml". Make sure the "FOSCommentBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" is not empty.)

Routes.yaml:

```
fos_comment_api:
type: rest
resource: '@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
prefix: /api
defaults: { _format: html }
```

I did not find any solution. Anyone knows what should I do or know any alternative bundle to comments' threads?

Comment: Just out of curiosity I loaded the comment bundle in a fresh 4.2 project and the routes seemed to work as expected.  Did you follow the suggestions in the error message and verify config/bundles.php as well as the existence of the FOSComment routing file?

Comment: "FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all', true],
    FOS\CommentBundle\FOSCommentBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],"
I have that added in bundles.php

Comment: And I assume you double checked that you have a vendor/friendsofsymfony/fos-comment directory.  Not too sure what else to try.  I just did a "composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton" followed by "composer require friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle" , added the db_driver config option and the route file entry.  Maybe try deleting the cache?  Maybe try a fresh project just to verify nothing else is messing things up.  But it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Find it, I had "['all', true]" instaed of ['all' => true] in bundles.php

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Strange you had to add the line.  In my case, simply doing the composer require allowed the Symfony recipe to automatically add the line.  I had to manually add the config file and routing section by hand which should have also been done automatically but bundles.php at least got updated.